# Mobile Browser Skewing Site Element sizes

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, web

My Apologies if the title was unclear, but I'm honestly not sure how to describe this issue, so I have a screenshot showing what I am talking about.

Here is a Screenshot from a Desktop Computer (Correct Appearance)
[image: Desktop scrot]

And here is a screenshot of the same site from an iPad (Skewed Appearance)
[image: iPad scrot]

I have no idea what is causing it, nor how to fix it. This is an issue I have seen on even big name websites before, from mobile.

If I had to guess, I would think perhaps the width of the widest element is wider than what the mobile browser has decided is 100%, therefore everything that has its width set to 100% is being limited while the other divs continue past that point?

Not sure, but if anyone has any solid information on this and any info on how to fix it that would be great!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to find the width of the "wrapper", write it down.
Find the element that is holding the image and navigation that is cut off, and add min-width: 1000px; (or whatever the wrapper width is)

Comment: That is exactly how I fixed it but that is more of a bandaid than an actual fix. Why is this issue caused in the first place. This issue plagues any percentage based elements. I have other designs that I'm building that use a percentage based layout for fluidity, and when this issue occurrs, it skews those as well. This issue makes automated fluidity impossible. I have to sit here and write specific stylesheets for handhelds and tablets and desktops seperately to handle what should happen automatically with a fluid layout? There has to be some other fix that resolves the underlying cause

Comment: When your mobile browser window width is set to something less than the wrapper this will occur. You can also avoid it by using something like <meta name="viewport" content="width=1000, user-scalable=yes">, where 1000 is the absolute widest section in pixels.

If your layout is 100% percentages, including sub elements such as images, this should not occur.

Have you any code to submit I can have a look at?